# Online quiz website by using PHP, MySQL and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm designing a website for online quiz system. I have made the database and few of webpages for login, question adding and all.

Now I am facing a problem in the following code. In this quiz page, I have one submit button and one link for the next question.

```
submit: to store the user option in database
next: to fetch the next question from database
```

Now I want that functionality of submit button is to be done by next link that is when I click the next then the user answer must be saved in the database and the next question must came from the database. How can I do this?

My code for that page is:

```
{<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "3,1";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
// For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
$isValid = False; 

// When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable      
  MM_Username set equal to their username. 
// Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable     
is blank. 
 if (!empty($UserName)) { 
  // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users   
  based on an ID established when they login. 
  // Parse the strings into arrays. 
  $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
  $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
 if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
  } 
  // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their 
 username. 
 if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
} 
return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "Login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) &&     
 (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'],  
 $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
$MM_qsChar = "?";
$MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
$MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" .  
urlencode($MM_referrer);
header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
exit;
}
?>
<?php
 if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
 function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",   
 $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
 if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
 $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
 }

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?   
 mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
 }
 }

 if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",  
$theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  
mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",   
$theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?   
mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

 $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "cprtc")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO usr_ans (u_name, topic, q_id, ansr) VALUES  
(%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['uname'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['topc'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['qid'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['RadioGroup1'], "text"));

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",    
$theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  
 mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_User = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
$colname_User = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_User = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE Username = %s",  
 GetSQLValueString($colname_User, "text"));
$User = mysql_query($query_User, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_User = mysql_fetch_assoc($User);
$totalRows_User = mysql_num_rows($User);

 $maxRows_qusnqz = 2;
 $pageNum_qusnqz = 0;
 if (isset($_GET['pageNum_qusnqz'])) {
  $pageNum_qusnqz = $_GET['pageNum_qusnqz'];
 }
 $startRow_qusnqz = $pageNum_qusnqz * $maxRows_qusnqz;

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
 $query_qusnqz = "SELECT * FROM quesns WHERE topic = 'C Language' ORDER BY 
 q_id ASC";
 $query_limit_qusnqz = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_qusnqz,  
 $startRow_qusnqz, $maxRows_qusnqz);
 $qusnqz = mysql_query($query_limit_qusnqz, $localhost) or    
 die(mysql_error());
 $row_qusnqz = mysql_fetch_assoc($qusnqz);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_qusnqz'])) {
$totalRows_qusnqz = $_GET['totalRows_qusnqz'];
 } else {
 $all_qusnqz = mysql_query($query_qusnqz);
  $totalRows_qusnqz = mysql_num_rows($all_qusnqz);
 }
 $totalPages_qusnqz = ceil($totalRows_qusnqz/$maxRows_qusnqz)-1;

  $queryString_qusnqz = "";
 if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
 $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
 $newParams = array();
 foreach ($params as $param) {
 if (stristr($param, "pageNum_qusnqz") == false && 
    stristr($param, "totalRows_qusnqz") == false) {
  array_push($newParams, $param);
 }
}
if (count($newParams) != 0) {
$queryString_qusnqz = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
}
}
 $queryString_qusnqz = sprintf("&totalRows_qusnqz=%d%s", $totalRows_qusnqz,   
 $queryString_qusnqz);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="CSS/Layout 5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Practise Quiz of C</title>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.js" type="text/javascript">   
 </script>
 <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationRadio.css" rel="stylesheet"   
 type="text/css" />
 </head>

 <body>
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"></div>
 <div id="NavBar">
<nav>
 <ul><li> <a href="Home.php" >Home</a></li>
   <li> <a href="Login.php" class="active">Login</a></li>
   <li> <a href="Regster.php"> Register</a></li>
   <li><a href="ForgetPassword.php"> Forgot Password</a></li>

  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
 <div id="PageHeading">
   <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $row_User['Fname']; ?> <?php echo   
  $row_User['Lname']; ?></h1>
  </div>
 <div id="ContentLeft">
  <h2>Account Links:</h2>
  <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
  <h6># <a href="Update.php">Update Account Info</a></h6>
  <h6># <a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></h6>
  <h6><br />
  </h6>
 </div>
 <div id="ContentRight">
  <?php if ($totalRows_qusnqz > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
    <?php do { ?>
      <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="cprtc" name="cprtc" 
         method="POST">
        <table width="620" border="0" cellpadding="1">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input name="qid" type="hidden" id="qid" value="<?php echo  
  $row_qusnqz['q_id']; ?>" />
              <input name="uname" type="hidden" id="uname" value="<?php echo 
  $row_User['Username']; ?>" />
              <input name="topc" type="hidden" id="topc" value="<?php echo 
  $row_qusnqz['topic']; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Question <?php echo ($startRow_qusnqz + 1) ?>:  
  </strong><strong>
              <label for="qsn"></label>
            </strong><?php echo $row_qusnqz['quesn']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="spryradio1">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="A" 
     id="RadioGroup1_0" />
                A</label>
              ) <?php echo $row_qusnqz['A']; ?><br />
              <br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="B"  
      id="RadioGroup1_1" />
                B</label>
              ) <?php echo $row_qusnqz['B']; ?><br />
              <br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="C" 
      id="RadioGroup1_2" />
                C</label>
              ) <?php echo $row_qusnqz['C']; ?><br />
              <br />
              <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="D" 
       id="RadioGroup1_3" />
                D</label>
              ) <?php echo $row_qusnqz['D']; ?><br />
              <span class="radioRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.</span> 
    </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><input name="Submit" 
 type="submit" class="styletxtfld" id="Submit" value="Submit" />                   
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td>        
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <?php if ($pageNum_qusnqz < $totalPages_qusnqz) { // Show if not last page 
         ?>
       <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_qusnqz=%d%s", $currentPage, min(4, 
     $pageNum_qusnqz + 1), $queryString_qusnqz); ?>"               
     class="styletxtfld">Next&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="cprtc" />
      </form>
      <?php } while ($row_qusnqz = mysql_fetch_assoc($qusnqz)); ?>
    <?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
    </div> 
 </div>
<div id="Footer"> 
 <h4>@Rituraj | <a href="AdminLogin.php" class="styletxtfld">Admin</a></h4>
 </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var spryradio1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationRadio("spryradio1");
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
 mysql_free_result($User);

  mysql_free_result($qusnqz);
  ?>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would store the Users question position in a session or database and then increment this value as he answers the questions.

You would then check the users question position and retrieve the correct question, or if no position found then return the first question and set his question position to one.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_question'])) $_SESSION['user_question'] = 1;

if(isset($_POST['next_question']) && $_POST['next_question']) {
    $_SESSION['user_question'] ++;

    // code to save question results in database
}

function get_next_question() {

    // code to retreive the next question data
}

get_next_question();
?>
```

Comment: how to do that..can u explain pls

Comment: I updated the question with some example code using sessions and a database.